# Repeat character depending on position in array + 1

Tags: javascript, function, methods, indexof, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
['h', 'ee', 'lll', 'llll', 'ooooo']
```

currently my out put is:

```
[ 'h', 'ee', 'lll', 'lll', 'ooooo' ]
```

The issue is the second occurrence of the "l" isn't being repeated one more time because I'm counting the index of the letter then adding 1 and it is only counting the first occurrence of the "l".
This is the code I have so far, any help would be great.

```
function mumble(string) {
  string.toLowerCase();
  let arrayPush = [];
  let array = string.split("");
  let count = 0;
  let char = [];
  array.map((letter) => {
    count = array.indexOf(letter);

    arrayPush.push(letter.repeat(count + 1));
  });

  return arrayPush;
}

console.log(mumble("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `indexOf`, use the second parameter in the `.map` callback to determine the index (and from that, the number of times to repeat the string).

```js
function mumble(string) {
  string.toLowerCase();
  let arrayPush = [];
  let array = string.split("");
  let count = 0;
  let char = [];
  array.map((letter, i) => {
    arrayPush.push(letter.repeat(i + 1));
  });

  return arrayPush;
}

console.log(mumble("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying `.map` to an array `split` from the string, you can simply loop through the string, accessing each character using the `.charAt()` string method, and pushing it's `.repeat()` product to the result  array.

Working snippet:

```js
console.log(mumble('hELlo'));

function mumble(string) {
const result = [];

for(let i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    result.push(string.toLowerCase().charAt(i).repeat(i+1));
}

return result;
} // end function mumble;
```